# Is there always a point with no gravitational acceleration?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Assuming that there are no 'point particles' but rather particles have finite size and density, and that the force of gravity is defined simply by Newton's law of gravitation:

$$F_g = -\dfrac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}\hat{r}$$

must there always be a point in space in which I would experience zero net force?

Considering small objects, the conjecture seems all right, for instance for a single spherical object of uniform density, an object placed at the centre of the sphere would be subject to 0 net force. For two objects, there will be a 'dead spot' of no net force along the line joining the two objects (if the objects are pretty normally shaped).

When I asked my friend this problem, he proposed that a solution could perhaps be constructed from an application of the [Hairy Ball Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem), though I'm not too sure how to apply this theorem. I would have posted this in Physics Stack exchange, but by using the approximations that I am using (ignoring relativity and using the Newtonian version) it seems more of a mathematical problem.

Comment: (I'm sorry if you don't know these terms, but I'm just wondering and this is more of a message to the rest of the community): As far as the hairy ball theorem goes, perhaps you could use stereographic projection from the 4-sphere to 3d space (correspondingly mapping the gravitational vectors), and apply the hairy ball theorem to the sphere? The issue is that the point corresponding to infinity would have a zero associated vector though, which poses an immediate issue that I don't see how to resolve.

Comment: @Shakespeare: Unfortunately the hairy ball theorem does not even hold for $S^3$ -- it's only for even-dimensional spheres. There are everywhere nonvanishing continuous vector fields on the 3-sphere because it has a Lie group structure (namely $SU(2)$) so you can just choose a vector at one point and translate it to other points using the group operation.

Comment: @HenningMakholm very true,I got confused about the dimension of the sphere. What if we try and project from $S^4$ in some intelligent way?

Comment: @Shakespeare: Won't fly either because there _are_ globally nonvanishing continuous vector fields on $\mathbb R^3$ that tend to zero at infinity -- such as $(x,y,z)\mapsto(0,0,\frac{1}{1+x^2+y^2+z^2})$ -- so we can't see by such purely topological reasoning that the _gravitational_ field in particular can't be one of them.

Comment: @HenningMakholm that is precisely what I was worried about in the second part of my comment. Moreover I see other problems with moving a dimension up. In fact, this approach simply could not work because as you say we haven't used the fact it's gravitational. Woulda been fun if it worked I guess, thank you for entertaining my curiosity :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Newtonian gravity is a conservative force, so the gravity field is can always be represented as the gradient of a gravitational *potential*.

If the source distribution is finite (otherwise we run into weird problems of conditional convergence anyway) we can always normalize the potential such that it is zero at infinity. Assuming that the mass density is globally bounded (which is a bit stronger than just assuming there are no point masses), the *potential* will be globally bounded too. And the potential is always negative too (there's no way Newton's law can produce a potential that is *higher* than that of infinity), so it will have a global minimum somewhere.

At this global minimum, the gravitational field (which is just the gradient of the potential) must be zero.

Comment: This is easier than trying to use the Hairy Ball Theorem!!

Comment: if the number of sources is finite (the number of planets or stars), I think we could prove it also by reccurence, noticing the force field is continuous with respect to the instensity of the sources, you can considerate the 3 sources case, then add another source progressively (starting with intensity (mass) $= 0$ and continuously increasing), showing that a zero-force point in the $n$ sources case will move continuously with respect to the instensity of the $n+1$th source added.

Comment: @reuns: But here I'm not assuming a finite _number_ of sources -- on the contrary I talking about a continuous mass distribution with finite total measure.

Comment: your trick works in the finite number of point-wise sources, right ? I was just  proposing an idea since you look to be familiar with the problem. and the sources in general are moving, so my idea of continuous relation to the sources position and intensity is useful in that case..

Comment: @reuns: No, it doesn't. On the contrary, with a finite number of point sources, the potential _will not_ have any global or local minimum, and you need to go to Joshua's answer instead.

Comment: ? with a finite number of point sources, each source produces a force $F(x) = C (x_0-x) /||x-x_0||^3 $ where $x_0$ is the position of the source, and it is still the gradient of a potential.

Comment: @reuns: I don't see what your point is. The gravitational potential of a finite number of point sources does not have a minimum anywhere (or at least not outside the sources, and _at_ the sources there's no well-defined gravitational field in the first place).

Comment: my points is what I explained, do the demonstration by recurrence, and with $2$ or $3$ sources there is a local saddle point at least, I don't see what YOUR point is, not understanding my simple comments. bye.

Comment: @reuns: Again, the stuff about saddle points is Joshua's answer, not mine. The argument you're sketching is not at all related to the one I'm giving. When you say "your trick works with a finite number of sources", that's simply wrong. My trick does NOT work with a finite number of sources. Joshua's trick seems to do.

Answer (score 12):

The globally bounded case is covered by @Henning. However, even if you consider point masses (which planets and stars almost are), and exclude them from consideration, you can show that there are points with zero gravitational force *in space* (away from the "point" sources), as soon as you have more than one point mass. How? All singularities are negative-valued and Morse theory tells you that there must be a saddle point between each two minima, so you can even tell *how many* saddle points there are for a given number of masses (assuming the symmetry is not such that they coincide in higher-order saddles). There are also no local maxima.

This is one of the reasons (at least hints) that a 3-body problem in general leads to chaotic motion: at a saddle point, small changes in input trajectory can lead to divergent output trajectories.

Comment: This is good stuff. Can you please describe the meaning of "between minima" more precisely? It doesn't seem likely that you mean the line connecting two minima unless there are exactly two point masses (a third object could be pulling to one side all along that line, no?. Is the idea to take some 3-simplex formed by local minima (when not all objects masses are coplanar) that is guaranteed to contain a saddle point?

Comment: This is a completely topological argument (that's why it's so general and powerful). Exact geometric position of the minimum can be almost arbitrary, as long as a graph, created by connecting neighbouring critical points has the right structure (imagine a topographical map of your favourite mountain range, you can apply Morse theory there to get a feeling). Of course, for a 1/r potential, things are more sensible - the potential satisfies Laplace equation where the average value theorem holds.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by, "All singularities are negative-valued"?

Comment: I just meant all have negative potential (all gravity is attractive, all gravity wells are minima).

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends. If you also allow an infinite universe with infinitely many objects and no upper bound on their density, then you can imagine an infinite array of objects. Say, a light object at the point $(1,0,0)$, a more massive one at $(2,0,0)$, even bigger one at $(3,0,0)$ et cetera. You can arrange their densities to grow in such a way that the gravitational field of the next object will overshadow all the preceding ones.

Of course, such a universe is not physically possible, and "everything would have been pulled to the end of the $x$-axes ages ago".

But if the number of objects is finite, then you can form the sum of their gravitational potentials. This approaches to zero as you go far away. Because there are no point masses, the potential will never go to $-\infty$. Therefore it has a global minimum somewhere (it is a continuous function and we just reduced the study to a compact set). The force of gravity will vanish at that global minimum.

Comment: While its a neat thought, allowing for infinite mass is what breaks it.  If you had infinite objects, but finite mass, you would also still get at least one point of 0 net gravity.  Of course, it would have to be telescoping smaller, not bigger objects along the x-axis.